# React native xcode is not working due to ReactCommon/jsi/JSCRuntime.h failrue

Tags: xcode, react-native

```
The following build commands failed:
   CpHeader /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-eclfaotwufydlccnbbpdrgkgblbf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi/jsi.framework/Headers/JSCRuntime.h /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/JSCRuntime.h (in target 'React-jsi' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I am getting this error last 3days and couldn't figure out what this is, and how to fix it. I can't even guess what this error is. I saw many other post and their err message are mostly about missing jsi file.

(I am not using expo)
Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.0",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by `pod install` and rerun every. After this I got another error

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/MyApp-eclfaotwufydlccnbbpdrgkgblbf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
(1 failure)
```

and it fixed by [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36293#issuecomment-1458033930)

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :
replace this line  #include <jsi/JSCRuntime.h> by this one

- #include <React-jsc/JSCRuntime.h>